# Query to select SUM of a single column based on date

Tags: mysql

Hello guys i've been having a problem getting the query for MySQL to select 2 sums.

I have a table like this

```
--------------------------------------
| im_id | cat |_id | qty | date_added |
--------------------------------------
```

i need to get the 2 sums of the quantity based on the date added, and grouping them by cat_id

how can i achieve this?

heres my query

```
select sum(qty), SUM(CASE WHEN date_added < CURDATE() THEN qty ELSE 0 END) 
from inventory_movement 
where dated_added <= CURDATE() 
GROUP BY cat_id
```

i am trying to get the ending inventory and beginning inventory based on the movement on this table?
can anyone help me?

Comment: Should be fine if you remove the WHERE clause; it's preventing your first sum from counting "today's" qty values.

Comment: Need more detail on the requirement. Final sentence doesn't really make sense.